# Python ./configure does not find g++ compiler

Tags: compile, g++

I'm trying to compile Python 3.4.1 on an emulated ARM machine (with Debian 7). `./configure` gives me

```
checking for g++... no
```

but g++ is installed. So what could be the problem? 
I know it's not strictly needed, but I'd prefer that `make` will use g++ for c++ code.

Comment: Are you sure `g++` is installed on the machine you're compiling on? What does `command -v g++` on that machine print? How did you install g++ on that machine?

Comment: Are you sure g++ is installed in the location that the build script is pointing to.

Comment: What does `g++ -dumpmachine` say? Run from same context as `./configure`

Comment: @AndrewStubbs: `root@debian:~/python3-3.4.1# command -v g++`
/usr/bin/g++ . I think g++ was preinstalled, since I've not installed any other related package.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm sure, since also gcc is in `/usr/bin`. Configure finds gcc but not g++. From configure source code it seems the search path is exactly the same.

Comment: @richard: `root@debian:~/python3-3.4.1# g++ -dumpmachine`
arm-linux-gnueabihf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Workaround:

```
CXX=/usr/bin/g++ ./configure
```

Anyway it's very strange and it seems to be a bug in the configure script. It seems to be a [known problem](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python3.html). Oh well...

---

**EDIT**: It seems that `--with-cxx-main` is an option with a different purpose. It's required on some platforms to support C++ extension modules. I updated my answer above.

Comment: See also issue report at http://bugs.python.org/issue25946

Answer (score 4):

You can set the location of g++ manually using an environment variable passed to configure, as described in the help:

```
Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...
```

For example, if you are running configure with a custom prefix your command would be:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/.local CXX="/usr/bin/g++"
```